# Laravel using a case statement

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve all messages of a conversation and display it's status (read or unread). With a `CASE` I try to read the message.read property (boolean) and process it to a string.

```
$messages = DB::table('conversation_message')
->select(
    'messages.id as message_id',
    'messages.created_at as send_at',
    'messages.user_id as from_id',
    'messages.body as body',
    'conversations.id as conversation',
    DB::raw('(CASE WHEN messages.read = 1 THEN read ELSE unread END) AS status')
)
->leftjoin('messages', 'messages.id', '=', 'conversation_message.message_id')
->leftjoin('conversations', 'conversations.id', '=', 'conversation_message.conversation_id')
->orderBy('send_at', 'asc')
->get();
```

Without the `CASE`, the query works fine but with the case I recieve a `Syntax error or access violation: 1064` near `'read`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by placing both the outcomes `read` and `unread` in double quotes.

```
$messages = DB::table('conversation_message')
->select(
    'messages.id as message_id',
    'messages.created_at as send_at',
    'messages.user_id as from_id',
    'messages.body as body',
    'conversations.id as conversation',
    DB::raw('(CASE WHEN messages.read = 1 THEN "read" ELSE "unread" END) AS status')
)
->leftjoin('messages', 'messages.id', '=', 'conversation_message.message_id')
->leftjoin('conversations', 'conversations.id', '=', 'conversation_message.conversation_id')
->orderBy('send_at', 'asc')
->get();
```

Now I can use the `status` directly as a css class!